# How Kafka Nodes and zookeeper will communicate with each other?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I could not find any details on communication between Nodes and Zookeeper . suppose
more Garbage collection is happening in Kafka nodes , What would be result of it ?

1. Will Zookeeper disconnect the communication with respective node ?
2. If Zookeeper will disconnect the respective node what would be result ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apache Kafka uses Zookeeper to select a controller, to maintain cluster membership and to store configuration, including the list of topics in the cluster.

In order to remain part of the Kafka cluster, each broker has to send keep-alive to Zookeeper in regular intervals. This is something every Zookeeper client does by default. If the broker doesn't heartbeat Zookeeper every `zookeeper.session.timeout.ms` milliseconds (6000 by default), Zookeeper will assume the broker is dead. This will cause leader election for all partitions that had a leader on that broker. If this broker happened to be the controller, you will also see a new controller elected.

So, if garbage collection pause takes longer than 6000 milliseconds, you will see the broker disconnecting from Zookeeper and a bunch of leader elections as a result. Since garbage collection pressure rarely results in just one long pause, you'll probably experience what we call "flapping" - brokers will keep disconnecting and reconnecting to Zookeeper, lots of leader elections and lots of ISR shrink/expand events.

The reverse is also true: If you see lots of broker "flapping", GC logs are a good place to start looking.

Comment: Straight from the horse's mouth :)